# How to make one sharp edge in subd modeling?

Tags: modeling, topology, subdivision-surface

Like picture below i want to make a sharp edge same way Crease does.
I tried to make one sharp edge with loop cut, inset, and bevel tool.
I can't figure it out how to do it in organic way.
Is there any technique?
 [image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you just need to add more vertical loop cuts if what you're looking to do is to emphasize the top mesh line.

[image: Fixed mesh]

I'm not sure what shape you're looking for by only sharpening the top edges, but try using the knife tool to cut in topology only where you need it. Use "K" to activate the knife tool, and "C" to cut in straight lines.

[image]

Comment: I want to sharp only top side's edge. When i did loop cut other edges also be sharpened as well.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure if I've got what you're looking for, but I've updated the answer a bit. Is that what you're looking for?